# Как поделить ассоциативный массив на другой?

Tags: php

```
   $cash = [
'uah' =>[
   'name' => 'Гривна',
   'course' => 1,
],
'usd'=>[
   'name' => 'Доллар',
   'course' => 27.1,
],
'eur'=> [
   'name' => 'Евро',
   'course' => 30.2,
],
];
 $date = [
 [
  'title' => 'Бегония',
  'price_val' => 300,
],
[
  'title' => 'Белый лотос',
  'price_val' => 400,
],
[
  'title' => 'Бромелия',
  'price_val' => 455,
],
[
  'title' => 'Георгин',
  'price_val' => 430,
],
[
  'title' => 'Желтый гибискус',
  'price_val' => 2040,
],
], как хочу использовать как конвертации для магазина
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросу пример того, что вы хотите сделать. Какие входные данные и какой результат.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перевести цены в другие валюты используя сессии?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270610/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Там нет ответа))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-нибудь в этом роде пишите

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use ($xchange){
                 $v['price'] = [
                           'uah' => $v['price_val'],
                           'usd' => $v['price_val'] / $xchange['usd']['course'],
                           'eur' => $v['price_val'] / $xchange['eur']['course'],
                       ] ;
                 // Общий случай
                 // $price = [];
                 // foreach($xchanges as $k=>$x){
                 //     $price[$k] = $v['price_val'] / $x['course'];
                 // } 
                 // $v['price'] = $price;
                 return $v;
             }, $data);
```

Comment: Благодарю ваш ответ сработал

Comment: Очень хорошо получилось

Comment: @Bebe хорошо так стрелку вверх ткните )

Comment: Рейтинга мало))